# How do I map a key combination to perform a command in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want the key combination `<C-X>` to run the command `:! python application.py`. From all my understanding of mapping, I tried the following: `:map <C-X> :! python application.py` which *almost* works. It just opens the command line and types the command in, but I still have to press return for the command to launch.

Is there any way I can get it to **run** the command as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer in an unrelated post while doing my last searches before posting the question. It seems that putting `<CR>` behind the command executes it, making this do what I wanted:

```
:map <C-X> :! python application.py<CR>
```

According to the comments (thanks to [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene)) `<CR>` means "carriage return", which in effect means "press enter" and is just what I needed in this case.

---

Slightly related, I also found out that `:!!` repeats the last shell command executed, making my map somewhat superfluous.

Comment: `<CR>` stands for "carriage return", which is indeed the key you want.

Comment: See `:h key-notation`. Well… learn how to read the doc first: 98% of what you'd want to ask is already there. And you should get into the habit of using `:nnoremap` and `:vnoremap` instead of `:map`, see [there](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) for the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can escape any key sequence with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (in Insert mode). So another way of getting the keycode for "Return" is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will come out looking like `^M`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `<C-V>` is mapped to paste in windows Gvim.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Try using Unix... :). For real though, try `<C-Q>`. Help says it equivalent to `<C-V>` specifically for the remap reason.